# IIS can't write logs to a symlink that references a network share

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, user-permissions

Good morning! 
I have one server running iis, and a folder located on another machine in a different network (and domain). 
I have successfully make a symlink to the network dir, but i can't understand why IIS can't write this dir.

I have grant permission on read, write, execute for everyone on this folder.
When i open this dir with file Explorer, everything go ok but iis give me error 500 when try to write on them. 
From logs results that my ASP application can't write to this dir. 
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I have tried for two days and now I'm ended my ideas. =(

Comment: Your file explorer is running under your identity, so it is not the same as the site's most likely. What identity does the site's application pool run under? It's possible that the identity cannot see the symlink, depending on how the symlink was created - not necessarily that it doesn't have permissions (which could also be the case). What is the exact error message(s) you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old and I don't know if there is a standard way of doing this but I have learned it must be done another way.

I am running two IIS 8.5 web servers under windows NLB and logging to separate folders on a DFS share. The servers share a configuration and DFS Replication maintains consistency of server content.

Each website has a **`logs`** symlink folder pointing its subfolder on the DFS share.

Server1: **`c:\inetpub\mywebsite\logs -> \\ad.mydomain.com\Logs\Server1\mywebsite`**
Server2: **`c:\inetpub\mywebsite\logs -> \\ad.mydomain.com\Logs\Server2\mywebsite`**

This is the functional equivalent of setting the site logging directory to
**`\\ad.mydomain.com\Logs\%COMPUTERNAME%\mywebsite`**.

This worked for me, for a while, but then stopped working. Naturally, it turned out to be **not one, but two problems**.

**The first was about permissions**.

**`Server1`** and **`Server2`** are part of the **domain `WebServers` group**, which has full control of the DFS share subfolders `Server1` and `Server2`, as does `Administrators` and `SYSTEM`, all of which are inherited from the share. Writing to the **`logs`** folders, for site application logs, by the website code, works fine.

But the IIS **`W3SVCxx`** log folders **do not get created** nor does creating them manually make any difference. **No IIS log files are created**.

Turns out, IIS requires full control permission be set specifically for the computer (**`%USERDOMAIN%\%COMPUTERNAME%`**) on the logging directory. I do not know why and can find no reference to explain it.

This permission exists on the `Server1` and `Server2` subfolders, apparently inherited from the share, even though the `Logs` parent folder does not have it. I did not add that permission, did not know of the requirement, and certainly believed the `WebServers` group permissions were sufficient. I do not know how those permissions were added.

But, this `%USERDOMAIN%\%COMPUTERNAME%` **permission** on the `Server1` and `Server2` subfolders **is not inheritable**. So the `ServerN\mywebsite` folders could not be written and the `W3SVCxx` subfolders were never created.

Adding this permission to the `Server1` and `Server2` folders solved that problem as long as I used **`\\ad.mydomain.com\Logs\%COMPUTERNAME%\mywebsite`** for the logging directory.

**The second problem had no resolution**.

While using the symbolic link **`c:\inetpub\mywebsite\logs -> \\ad.mydomain.com\Logs\%COMPUTERNAME%\mywebsite`** did work, in the beginning, and worked for a little while after fixing the permissions issue, it stopped working, again, and I could not find any information to explain why.

**Conclusion**

The only real advantage to setting the IIS logging directory to the site name folder was I didn't need to know the site ID to find the correct `W3SVCxx` folder. But, being a minimalist by nature, I decided to ignore the permissions problem and set the logging directory for the websites to **`\\ad.mydomain.com\Logs\%COMPUTERNAME%`**. Having to look up the site ID is a small price to pay to have my logs back.

I strongly suggest this solution and to stay away from logging to symlinks, if at all possible.